# Pasar variables VB.net a Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Es posible si yo defino mis variables en vb.net framework 2 pasarlos a una funciona en javascript, de prueba eh intentado esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<%=Rotulo.ID%>");
```

pero me da error, ayuda amigos

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que hice fue utilizar la siguiente Funcion:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "initMyClientVariable", String.Format("var variable1 = '{0}'; var variable2 = '{1}'", System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(valorvariable1), valorvariable2), True)
```

esto lo puse en el evento load de la pagina para setear las variables antes de llamar el recurso javascript ojo eso es muy importante